# End of proof sign outside table

Tags: tables, math-mode

How to insert an end of proof sign outside a table (on the right on the table, on the same last line)?

So far, I only managed to insert the end of proof sign in the bottom-right cell of my table, or on the next line. Any help would be very appreciated. Thanks.

Edit: For example, see the following code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{| c | c |}
\hline
A & B \\ \hline
C & D $\square$ \\  \hline  $\square$
\end{tabular}
$\square$
\end{document}
```

I would like the square on the second line CD of my table, but outside the table.

Comment: Could you provide a MWE (Minimum Working Example)?

Comment: It looks like you're trying to hand-craft a commutative diagram. Have you thought of using the `amscd` package for this? If you do use this package, it also won't be difficult to get your end-of-proof sign at the right position. TikZ also supports commutative diagrams.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with `\documentclass{...}`, the required `\usepackage`'s, `\begin{document}`, and `\end{document}`. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for TeX.SX users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

Answer (score 1):

The problem here is that, by default, a table is vertically centered in the text around it, so the `$\square$` that you place after the table is centered, along with the rest of the text.

[image]

You can override this with `\begin{tabular}[b]{| c | c |}`: the `[b]` makes the bottom of the table aligned with the bottom of the text, and the `$\square` aligned with the bottom cell of the table:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\begin{document}
Some text before the table and
\begin{tabular}[b]{| c | c |} % <-- here
\hline
A & B \\ \hline
C & D
\end{tabular}
$\square$ and then some after.
\end{document}
```

[image]

See [this link](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Tables#The_tabular_environment) for more options provided by the `tabular` environment.